# How can I use XML serializer in Perl Dancer2?

Tags: xml, perl, dancer

In Dancer you can use:

```
set serializer => 'Mutable';
```

or

```
set serializer => 'XML'
```

Dancer2:

```
set serializer => 'XML'
```

you got

```
Unable to load class for Serializer component XML: Can't locate Dancer2/Serializer/XML.pm
```

There is no `Dancer2::Serializer::XML` in CPAN.

Mutable in Dancer2 only support only JSON, YAML, Dumper :-(

Comment: There is no serializer for XML in Dancer2 yet and also there's no module on CPAN. That's one of the (few?) situations where Dancer1 is still superior to Dancer2. But you can wriite your `Dancer2::Serializer::XML` quite easily or just encode your data into XML "by hand".

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick shot to get you started:

```
package Dancer2::Serializer::XML;
use Moo;
use Carp 'croak';
use Encode;
use Class::Load 'load_class';
with 'Dancer2::Core::Role::Serializer';

has '+content_type' => ( default => sub {'text/xml'} );

sub BUILD { load_class('XML::Simple') }

sub serialize {
    my ( $self, $entity ) = @_;
    XML::Simple::XMLout($entity);
}

sub deserialize {
    my ( $self, $content ) = @_;
    XML::Simple::XMLin($content);
}

1;
```

I just assembled this from [`Dancer::Serializer::XML`](https://metacpan.org/source/YANICK/Dancer-1.3132/lib/Dancer/Serializer/XML.pm) and [`Dancer2::Serializer::YAML`](https://metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/Dancer2-0.158000/lib/Dancer2/Serializer/YAML.pm). It's far from finished or ready for release but maybe it's a start for you?

I offer this as community wiki answer.

Comment: Since 2012 (2.5 years before this answer was posted), XML::Simple has documented itself as being deprecated.  Why?  It doesn't support unicode.  This sample code looks a lot like the Dancer2::Serializer::XML module now in CPAN... which likewise uses XML::Simple and therefore breaks on unicode. :(

Comment: @TheAmigo I didn't know about this and also find this is a severe weakness in 2020. I think you should probably file this as a bug for the serializer module and it’s probably gonna be fixed.